# iptable rule to redirect only https handshake?

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, https

I was reading this interesting article today: http://www.moserware.com/2009/06/first-few-milliseconds-of-https.html

A crazy thought came to mind...Is it possible to write an iptable rule that only redirects https handshake requests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  You can't know it's a HTTPS handshake until the [connection is open](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_establishment).  At that point, it's too late to redirect it.  The SYN packet doesn't tell you what's going to be transmitted; that's why we have port numbers to begin with.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  That's what I was afraid of. :-(